# Will the kernel hold the whole file to which some process is writing

Tags: files, filesystems, rm, file-descriptors, inode

After posing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64335276/why-can-a-program-which-writes-to-a-file-keep-running-without-any-error-even-i), I'm kind of confused by the action of the linxu kernel.

First of all, I know how a process writes strings into a file: a process will obtain some buffer, the buffer can be written by the process, once the buffer is full or the process flushes the buffer, the content of the buffer will be written into the **data block** of the file. For example, in the program of C, when we `printf` a `\n`, it will flush the buffer.

Now, let's consider the case in the post above: a process has opened a file and is writing to it while the file is deleted by the comomand `rm`.

As my understanding, the command `rm` will unlink the file, meaning that **its inode and its data blocks** will be marked as `UNUSED`. So we can't access it through the filename anymore. And if a process opens a file, the kernel will create a file descriptor to access it.

So if I'm right, `rm` a file, to which a process is writing, won't cause any error of the process, because the process could access the file through the file descriptor. As someone mentioned in the comment of that post, we can still access the file through `cat /proc/<pid>/fd/3`.

Now I'm confused. If we can still access the file through `cat /proc/<pid>/fd/3` while the inode and the data have been marked as `UNUSED` because of `rm`, does it mean that the kernel will hold the whole file in RAM? If so, if the file is very huge, such as some log file, does it mean that lots of RAM will be used?

In a word, if a file isn't `rm`ed, a process can write things into the buffer and once the buffer is flushed, its content will be written into the data blocks of the file. But if a file has been `rm`ed, its data blocks will be marked as `UNUSED` but a process can still write to **it**. Where is this "**it**"?

Comment: I am writing this on the fly without access to a system to test yet, but I don't think `rm` will actually unlink the file like it would under normal circumstances. A couple of years ago, I ram some tests on this, and if I recall correctly `rm` will only unlink the file in "totallity" ,if and only if, all file descriptions from other processes stop first. Command `lsof` is used to check for these handles on files, especially if there is a large file to delete to reclaim space, which cannot be done until terminating all corresponding handles.

Comment: One additional note. I am not familiar with `<unused>` in `lsof` output but <deleted> i.e. to check for locked deleted files I was taught to do  `sudo lsof | grep delete` as that will show files that are "seemingly deleted", but still have their file descriptor held by another process with listed PID. Your file doesn't actually get touched until the linked processes terminate. The file isn't actually held in RAM (unless it is a RAM based system) but instead can have a web of links connected to it. Only when all of them (from various processes) are cut does the file fall into the abyss.

Comment: @BarBar1234 So do you mean that the data blocks won't be touched (maybe the inode won't be touched either?) if some process is holding its file descriptor, even if we `rm` the file?

Comment: Yes, the data blocks won't be touched, as the inode is still "held" open and the file can be indeed recovered using the round-robin method i.e.  imagine the file to be "accidentally" deleted is `file1`. If we first "hold" the file through another process `nano file1` for exe, followed `rm file1` , then get PID of `nano` with `lsof | grep file1| awk '{print $2}'` , and find it with `find /proc/PID -type f -exec ls -l {} | grep file1 \;` , (the `-exec` part may need work) and finally `cp /proc/PID/[pathoffile] temp1` will bring the `file1` back

Comment: @BarBar1234 I got it. Great explanation.

Comment: BUT, the file we just restored is not the original file `file1`, the restored inode and block value reported by `stat file1` will be different from those reported by the original (pre `rm). The last part is very important, there can actually be multiple links to that file all at different stages of modification (our case was simply with single holding process) thus going with the first handle found when restoring, may not result in the most recent version of `file1` i.e. its state immediately before `rm` was executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As my understanding, the command `rm` will unlink the file, meaning that **its inode and its data blocks** will be marked as `UNUSED`.

This is the key to understanding what’s going on here: `rm` only asks the kernel to remove a given directory entry. If the directory entry pointed to an inode which is no longer referenced by anything else (other directory entries, open file descriptions, file mappings, loop mounts etc.), the kernel will also free the inode and the associated data.

Thus the kernel doesn’t need to keep the deleted file’s data: it’s still there, wherever the file system keeps it. As long as a process holds a file descriptor pointing at it, it will remain there, and can be recovered through `/proc/.../fd/...` on Linux.

Comment: "other directory entries or open file descriptions" add active memory mappings to that. The kernel will cling on the whole inode even if only *some* parts of the file are memory mapped. On Linux, memory mapped files can be accessed similarly to `proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` via `/proc/<pid>/map_files/<range>` (but depending on the kernel version, subject to more stringent access restrictions)

Comment: @user414777 good point, thanks for the reminder; there’s also loop mounts.